# API for printers?

Tags: java, php, json, api, printing

i was searching about some api's for printers but i can't find anything, maybe cause i'm searching that bad.

I wonder if there is any API which i can send some json code (or like that) as that example:

```
 nameFile:"document.pdf",
 url:"blabla/documents/document.pdf",
 pages:"5"
```

etc. And the printer "understands" that and start printing.

At all what i'm searching is some code that give's data to printer and these printer starts printing (fck, i need more English classes..)

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javax Print API, and write a utility to convert your own JSON input format to appropriate print api calls.

[Refer this for sample program.](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/javaxprintAPIandallowsyoutolistavailableprintersqueryanamedprinterprinttextandimagefilestoaprinterandprinttopostscriptfiles.htm)